# servo motors not working as expected for facetracking using pantilt

Tags: python, opencv, iot, servo

i have used servo motors for pantilt  to track faces 
but the thing is the servo aren't directly connected to the raspberry 
instead im using 16channel adafruit pca9685 to control the servos
all the tutorials which teach face-tracking using raspberry aren't using such channels so i tried to figure out my own ways of making it happen

```
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format = 'bgr', use_video_port = True):
        image = frame.array

        resized = cv2.resize(image, (320, 240))
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 5)
        if len(faces) > 0:
            for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                # Track(pan, tilt, Point(x + w/2.0, y+ h/2.0))
                break
        faces_resized = [(int(scale[0]*x), int(scale[1]*y), int(scale[0]*w), int(scale[1]*h)) for (x, y, w, h) in faces]
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces_resized:
            cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,0),2)
```

to this part the code is absolutely clear the face is getting detected perfectly  fine but using this i want to track and change my servo motors position

i just need the code that makes it happen 
my adafruit board code structure

```
            pwm.set_pwm(0, 0,cam_pan)
0 for index of channels 
0 min angle
```

cam_pan the angle it is supposed to move

considering those parameters i just want to control the movements of my servo/pantilt to move accordingly

i have tried to control the motors through this

```
x = x + (w/2)
        y = y + (h/2)

        # Correct relative to center of image
        turn_x  = float(x - (FRAME_W/2))
        turn_y  = float(y - (FRAME_H/2))

        # Convert to percentage offset
        turn_x  /= float(FRAME_W/2)
        turn_y  /= float(FRAME_H/2)

        # Scale offset to degrees
    turn_x   = 2 # VFOV
    turn_y   = 2 # HFOV
    if x > turn_x:
        cam_pan  += -turn_x
        pwm.set_pwm(0, 0,cam_pan)
    elif x < turn_x:

        cam_pan  += +turn_x
        pwm.set_pwm(0, 0,cam_pan)
```

but its of no use the servo motors just started jerking a bit

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2
# from pisoc import *
import Adafruit_PCA9685
pwm = Adafruit_PCA9685.PCA9685()
FRAME_W = 180
FRAME_H = 100
cam_pan = 90
cam_tilt = 60

if __name__ == "__main__":

    camera = PiCamera()
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    camera.framerate = 32
    rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size = camera.resolution)

    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/usr/local/share/OpenCV/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml')

    scale = (camera.resolution[0]/320.0, camera.resolution[1]/240.0)

    time.sleep(0.1)

    for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format = 'bgr', use_video_port = True):
        image = frame.array

        resized = cv2.resize(image, (320, 240))
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 5)
        if len(faces) > 0:
            for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                # Track(pan, tilt, Point(x + w/2.0, y+ h/2.0))
                break
        faces_resized = [(int(scale[0]*x), int(scale[1]*y), int(scale[0]*w), int(scale[1]*h)) for (x, y, w, h) in faces]
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces_resized:
            cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,0),2)
            # Track first face

            # Get the center of the face
            x = x + (w/2)
            y = y + (h/2)

            # Correct relative to center of image
            turn_x  = float(x - (FRAME_W/2))
            turn_y  = float(y - (FRAME_H/2))

            # Convert to percentage offset
            turn_x  /= float(FRAME_W/2)
            turn_y  /= float(FRAME_H/2)

            # Scale offset to degrees
        turn_x   = 2 # VFOV
        turn_y   = 2 # HFOV
        if x > turn_x:
            cam_pan  += -turn_x
            pwm.set_pwm(0, 0,cam_pan)
        elif x < turn_x:

            cam_pan  += +turn_x
            pwm.set_pwm(0, 0,cam_pan)
        # cam_tilt += turn_y


        # Clamp Pan/Tilt to 0 to 180 degrees
        # cam_pan = max(0,min(180,cam_pan))
        # cam_tilt = max(0,min(180,cam_tilt))

        # Update the servos
        # pwm.set_pwm(0, 0,cam_pan)

            # print(cam_pan-90, cam_tilt-90)
            #
            # # Clamp Pan/Tilt to 0 to 180 degrees
            # cam_pan = max(0,min(180,cam_pan))
            # # cam_tilt = max(0,min(180,cam_tilt))
            #
            # # Update the servos
            # pwm.set_pwm(0, 0,cam_pan)
            #
            # # pan(int(cam_pan-90))
            # # tilt(int(cam_tilt-90))

            break


        cv2.imshow("Result", image)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        rawCapture.truncate(0)

        if key == ord('q') or key == 27:
            break
```

here is the complete code

i dont what exactly the issue is 
im not even sure if the issue is with the code part 
but i just want to change servo motors according to the face

Comment: Sounds like part of the problem is trying to get it all to work together at once. Small testable units are key. Have you been able to move the servos independently?

If not, try to set up a smaller test program that *only* moves the servos back and forth and step up from there.

Comment: yes i have tried runinng it as units and its working perfectly fine